# What is default Puppet username and password?

Tags: linux, puppet

Just installed Puppet and I need to configure it using web.

I am trying to log in for the first time and do not know the username and password.

Does anybody know what is the default username and password for Puppet?

Thanks

Comment: You seem confused.  You cannot log in to Puppet itself.  Installing Puppet on a machine requires that you be able to log in to that machine already, and performing such an installation does not, in itself, change or add any login credentials, so you should still be able to log in to that machine.

Comment: If you are using Puppet *Enterprise* then there is a web-based dashboard / control center, but I would be surprised if there were a default password for it.

Comment: I am using Puppet Enterprise. I do not know username and password.

Comment: Well, my expectation would be that you were *prompted* for the password during installation.  If that was not the case, or if you have forgotten the password that you provided, then you should find the login password for the management console in file 'pe.conf' somewhere under directory /etc/puppetlabs.  In that file, look for key 'console_admin_password'.

Answer (score 1):

After installation, login as root (not sudo, didn't work for me) and enter the following:

```
puppet infrastructure console_password --password=<MY_PASSWORD>
```

Comment: This is correct, no default password is set. The default username to login to the console is "admin". When you run the installer script for Puppet Enterprise it does show you this command at the end and then tells you to run puppet agent -t twice.

Answer (score 0):

Has to do with noexec on /tmp . Fix by editing /etc/sysconfig/puppetserver, add something like “-Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/puppettmp” , mkdir /var/puppettmp, chmod 1777 /var/puppettmp .